# Geodesics in a manifold M diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I am now reading the book [Calculus of Variations](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Calculus_of_Variations.html?id=QN8Iw7fUA-8C&redir_esc=y) written by Jost and I encountered the following problem (in Theorem 2.3.3.):

Let $M$ be a differentiable submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$. By the compactness and connectedness of $M$, $\forall\ p, q \in M$ with $p \neq q$, there exists a shortest geodesic connecting $p$ and $q$.

Now, what we want to do is to construct a diffeomorphism $$h_0: \mathbb S^2 \rightarrow M$$ with the following properties:

$$p = h_0(0, 0, 1), q = h_0(0, 0, -1)$$ and a shortest geodesic arc $c: [0, 1] \rightarrow M$ with $c(0) = p, c(1) = q$ is given by $$c(t) = h_0(0, \sin \pi t, \cos \pi t).$$

This problem is intuitively true and I have tried "shifting" the inverse image of a geodesic smoothly to a part of a great circle, but I have yet to write down the proof successfully. Thus, I would really like to know if there is anyone who can help me solving this problem or give me some hints. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the last equation you, perhaps, want $t$ instead of $x$ in the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Let $x_0, y_0\in I := [0, 1]$ such that $x_0 < y_0$. Choose a positive real number $\epsilon < x_0$ and a smooth transition function $f$ from the level $0$ to the level $1$ in the interval $I$, that is an increasing smooth function such that $f(x) = 0$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x\geq 1$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions) for a concrete example).

The map defined on $I$ by
$$
F(x) := \alpha x + k f\left( \frac {x - \epsilon}{x_0 - \epsilon} \right)
$$
where
$$
\alpha := \frac {1 - y_0} {1 - x_0}\\
k := \frac {y_0 - x_0} {1 - x_0}
$$
is a strictly increasing smooth function with positive derivative, therefore it is invertible and $F^{-1}$ is smooth. Since
$$
F(0) = 0\\
F(x_0) = y_0\\
F(1) = 1\\
F^{(n)}(0) = F^{(n)}(1)\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N 
$$
you can think of $F$ as a (smooth) diffeomorphism of $\mathbb S^1$ onto itself, which sends $x_0$ to $y_0$ and leaves $0\equiv 1$ fixed.